# Stop Decimal Values From Being Entered into C Program

Tags: c

I have a program which takes input from the user and tells the user which number is bigger **num1** or **num2**. My problem is that i don't want to allow the user to enter a decimal number such as **1.2** etc.

Here is my program so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
   int num1;
   int num2;

   printf("enter a number: ");
   scanf("%d", &num1);
   printf("enter another number: ");
   scanf("%d", &num2);

   printf("\n");
   printf("\n");

   if (num1 < 0) {
       printf("Enter a value which is not below 0!");
   }
   else if (num1 == num2) {
       printf("%d and %d are equal", num1, num2);
   }
   else if (num1 > num2) {
       printf("%d is bigger than %d", num1, num2);
   }
   else if (num2 > num1) {
       printf("%d is bigger than %d", num2, num1);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Currently my program displays an error message if a user enters a negative number.

But I want to deter and stop any decimal numbers from being entered at all weather below 0 as a negative number or not.

Comment: Your code looks like C but it could be C++. It certainly doesn't look like C#. Please pick only one language tag.

Comment: Just a side node: 1) you're calling ````printf("\n")```` twice, while you also could call ````printf("\n\n")```` once, 2) if a number isn't equal, nor bigger, it must be smaller, so you could leave out the last `else if`-statement and make it just an `else`.

Comment: @BlayerBond In regards to what you said about the else statement I thought "else" was used as a default option in C, where if no tests return true then it resorts to the "else" at the end.

Comment: That's exactly what's happening: it's not equal, it's not greater, so no tests return `true`. The performance can't be that big to worry about, but it looks like bad practice to me. You could as well just write a comment after `else` to clarify the last statement.

Comment: @BlayerBond Ah ok thanks for the tips, any other things you'd reccomend I'm new too C also any ideas for my question?

Comment: @Qasim, the rest looks okay ;) I assume you're aware of it, but you can leave out the library `<math.h>`, since you're not calling a single math function and `<stdlib.h>` as well, since all you do is using `printf` and `scanf`, which is in the `<stdio.h>` library. If you're not sure what to include, check out these documentaries: [this on is stdlib.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot, with standard Console input, prevent the user from entering arbitrary strings. (That would require to receive every single character as it is typed, and suppress "illegal" characters, which is both system specific). So you are stuck with receiving a stream of input and checking its contents. If the input was wrong, you can prompt the user to try again.

There are two basic ways:

1. You *do* read floating point numbers with `%f`. This format skips any whitespace, then tries to parse a number from the following word, and stops when it encounters a character which does not let it continue parsing a number. (That is typically another whitespace separating it from the next number but could be a letter or any other non-numerical character.) Then you check whether it is a whole number. The easiest way to do that is to  cut the fraction part of the parsed value and see whether it is equal to the parsed float. An easy way to cut off any decimal places is to truncate it to int: `if((int)f != f) { /* user entered a number with decimal places */ }`.
2. You read a word from the input *as a string* (`%s`) and parse it manually. That's more complicated but actually a pretty neat beginner exercise, in particular if you try to come up with all possible stupid inputs (unprintable characters, very long words, several minus sings etc.) and test and harden your routine against them.

One important advice: Whatever way you decide to go, **make sure to evaluate the return value of the input routine.** I see that you do not evaluate the return value of `scanf` in your program, but that is essential. `scanf`  returns the number of successfully converted items (i.e. in your case 1 if a number could be read). **If `scanf` returns 0, it could not parse a number from the input** (for example because the first character in the input is a decimal point which cannot be part of an integer number), and **you have to perform some kind of error handling.** In particular, you must read away the offending word (or line? Depends on the strictness you want to impose on the input format) of the input.

Another advice on the side is to prepare your program for non-interactive use. This means that there is nobody sitting in front of a console entering numbers and hitting enter — instead the standard input comes from a file or another program. In order to provide input from a file one would write `myprog < sometextfile.txt` in a Console on Windows as well as in a Linux etc. terminal. Programs profit enormously from being "scriptable"; it also makes it easy to quickly test them against many kinds of input in a repeatable fashion. But if the input comes potentially from a file there is, for example, no need to expect every number (or every pair of numbers)  to be on its own line.

Comment: Can we use scanset?

Comment: @intsoumen You mean a conversion specifier like `%[0-9]`? Yes, of course. But the benefit of using `%[0-9]` over using a simple `%d` is not immediately clear to me. (OK, you exclude negative numbers, but you still must transform the string to an integer.) The `[0-9]` notation does not magically prevent the user from entering arbitrary characters. In both cases the scanning will stop when the first non-grammatical character is encountered (e.g. a dot, a letter or a newline), and the remaining chars will stay in the input.

Answer (score 0):

1.2 is not a decimal data type. It is a float data type!
As you've used %d in the scanf, the value before . will get stored in num1 and 0 will be stored in num2;

`int num1,num2;
 scanf("%d%d",&num1,&num2);
 printf("%d %d",num1,num2);`

if entered 1.2 & 3.4
o/p:- 1 0

if entered 1 & 3.4
o/p:- 1 & 3

Comment: Do you want that user should input only one digit at a time? If yes then, use %1d instead of %d. It'll allow only one digit at a time!

Answer (score 0):

Try this concept - ['Scanset' or 'Negated Scanset'](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

```
scanf("%[^.]", &num1); // does not allow decimal point (.) and will accept not only number but all other characters
```

or

```
scanf("%[0-9]", &num1); // only accept positive integer
```